# Why in self hosted API C# PUT method is not working as expected

Tags: c#, api

I was following thru this tutorial:
http://johnatten.com/2015/01/11/asp-net-web-api-2-2-create-a-self-hosted-owin-based-web-api-from-scratch/
and i need to have PUT method with url like this:

```
PUT: /companies/update/<id> for example: localhost:8080/api/companies/update/1
```

and with above URL i'm passing JSON in request body:

```
{
    "Id": 100,
    "Name": "Microsoft"
}
```

and I have in controller new method like this:

```
[HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult update(int id, Company company)
        {
            int a = id;
            return Ok();
        }
```

with company like this:

```
 public class Company
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

When i try to debug "update" method thru POSTMAN, method is not hit and there is no error in response.

When I remove ID from  URL like this:

```
localhost:8080/api/companies/update
```

Method is debug-able but cant pass ID to update...

Any advise how to reach desired effect?

Comment: Isn't the ID already included inside the Company model? Just wondering why you need to pass it separately

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things

1. You need to specify that you will be sending Id as part of the Route
2. You need to let know your data will be the part of the body

So the code should look like

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("update/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult update(int id, [FromBody] Company company)
    {
        int a = id;
        return Ok();
    }
```

Then in postman your URL should be localhost:8080/api/companies/update/1
Where 1 is the Id